# Python - Skip line that contains specific text if it has been read already and column to row based on criteria

Tags: python-3.x

I have a long file of letters which contains a persons ID number and several plans that they are eligible for based on criteria. The ID is at the beginning and end of every letter. I have been able to achieve the output below so far.

```
    Current Output:
    ID1
    Plan1
    Plan3
    ID1
    ID2
    Plan2
    Plan3
    Plan4
    ID2
    ID3
    etc....

    #Current Code:
    import re
    #The input file path is where the file you would like manipulated is
    Input = open(r"Original File Filepath", "r")
    #The output file path is where you want the lines extracted to
    Output = open(r"Destination Filepath", "w")
    #Below just change the green areas to the text on the lines you would   
    like extracted
    for line in Input:
        if re.match("(.*)ID(.*)", line):
            Output.writelines(line)
        if re.match("(.*)Plan1(.*)", line):
            Output.writelines(line)
        if re.match("(.*)Plan2(.*)", line):
            Output.writelines(line)
        if re.match("(.*)Plan3(.*)", line):
            Output.writelines(line)
        if re.match("(.*)Plan4(.*)", line):
            Output.writelines(line)
    Output.close()
```

I am trying to get the second ID not to be written and the results to go to a specific column in a csv as an "X" alias based on plan.

```
    Desired Output:
    ID,Plan1,Plan2,Plan3,Plan4
    ID1,X,,X,
    ID2,,X,X,X
```

Edit: The list of letters would look something like the below-

Dear Ms. Smith                             ID 1234

You are informed that yada yada yada
(Text block here)

ID 1234

You are eligible for the plans below

First one

That one

Dear Mr. Jones                               ID 598

You are informed that yada yada yada
(Text block here)

ID 598

You are eligible for the plans below

This one

That one

Or the Other

Comment: Can we see a sample of the input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to try:

```
Output.write("ID,Plan1,Plan2,Plan3,Plan4")
current_id, current_plan = None, 0
for line in Input:
    match = re.match("(.*)(ID.)(.*)", line)
    if match:
        current_plan = 0
        if current_id == None:
            current_id = match.group(2)
             Output.write("\n" + current_id)
        else:
            current_id = None
    for i in range(current_plan,5):
        if re.match("(.*)Plan{}(.*)".format(i), line):
            Output.write("," * (i - current_plan) + "X")
            current_plan = i
            break
```

Comment: Thank you much! The actual letters had the "Plans" listed by name. All I had to do was run a find and replace changing their names to "Slan1" through "Slan4." Had to change them to this because the word "Plan" was used several times in the body of the letters. Then modified the code you provided to ("(.*)Slan{}(.*)" Worked like a charm!